# Regular Expression: Match string that can be or not at beginning or end of text

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to find a string with three possible forms:

```
ab10
ab 10
ab-10
```

So far I have managed to create this regular expression,

```
/\s+[a-zA-Z]{2}[-|\s.]?\d{2,3}\s+/
```

that works for a text like:

```
start foo ab 10 end foo.
```

The problem appears when the searched string is at the beginning or at the end of the text like:

```
ab 10 end foo.
```

In this case there is no whitespace at the beginning.  So I need to match if the string is at the beginning (or end) of the text, but I have no clue how to do it

Can someone give me a little help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fix your problem:

```
/\b[a-zA-Z]{2}[-|\s.]?\d{2,3}\b/
```

`\b` means word boundary, and it asserts that one side (either before or after the current position) is non-word character and the other side is word character (word character as defined by `\w`).

Note that if you have a string like `#ab10.`, then `ab10` will still be matched. But `_ab10` will give no match because `_` is a word character.

In case you want to assert that the character before and after the string you want to search has to be whitespace character (as defined by `\s`), OR start/end of the line. I employ the use of look-behind and look-ahead zero-width assertion.

```
/(?<=^|\s)[a-zA-Z]{2}[-|\s.]?\d{2,3}(?=\s|$)/
```

The regex above will not find any match in `#ab10.` or `ab10.`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b`

```
/\b[a-zA-Z]{2}[-|\s.]?\d{2,3}\b/
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?32sp8)

That matches now, when there is not a word character before and not a word character following.

A word character is a member of the predefined character class `\w` that are letters, digits and the underscore.